# disable event-bubbling c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, event-bubbling

I'm having the following problem:

When I got two labels into each other:

```
<Label x:Name="First" MouseUp="Label_MouseUp">
    <Label x:Name="Second" MouseUp="Label_MouseUp_1">This is a label into another label</Label>
</Label>
```

And the following code:

```
private void Label_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do NOT show me");
}

private void Label_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Show me");
}
```

When i click "Second", I want it to trigger only "Label_MouseUp_1". But in my console i get:

Show me 
 Do NOT show me

Is there a way to turn off the bubbling events?

(also, "First" has to be clickable, so removing the event there doesn't solve the problem)

Thnx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't have the docs right in front of me, but I think if you mark the MouseButtonEventArgs object as Handled it stops the event from going up the chain.

Should be as simple as

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Please somebody correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: That's a quick anwser :)
I'm going to try this at once.
Thanks a lot