# Select a Control alone inside a ListView not the whole ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a `ListView` with `ItemTemplate` contains an `Image`, `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, `TextBlock` etc when selecting any control should highlight the selected control not the whole `ListViewItem` any style would be fine.

### XAML

```
<ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding TCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTImage}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Width="70" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="300" DecodePixelHeight="300" UriSource="{Binding TImage}"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding text}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Contents"/>
                    <ComboBox/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to disable event bubbling. Sure, it hits the control first, but the click event bubbles to the list item, too. In order to stop it, you have to put an event handler on all the controls (button, etc) and set `e.Handled = true` in the handler to prevent it from going to the `ListViewItem`.

See: [disable event-bubbling c# wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498305/disable-event-bubbling-c-sharp-wpf) for more info.

If you never want items to be selected at all (hard to tell with your example), then you'd want to use an [`ItemsControl`](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) instead. That will let you bind to a collection of items and display all of them but it doesn't have the concept of a selected item.

Comment: can we stop event bubbling in XAML ?